# How to skip the downloading update while the terminal is downloading?

Tags: command-line, updates

I want to know how to skip the downloading update while the terminal is downloading. I  am currently updating from terminal and I want to skip a package from being downloaded because it will consume a lot of time.

Comment: If it's from the same repository, like the main repos,  I don't think you can skip. However you can download individual PPAs all by itself without downloading all of the other software sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to download update of any package , you can use temporary holding and unholding command.

- hold : it will stop updating a specific package.
- unhold : removes hold for a package which is being hold.

**usage**:

For example I dont want to update my firefox because i have to download 20MB which is high data for my 236kbps modem so I dont want to update it now . so i will put it in hold.

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

so except firefox all packages will download and installs.

If I want to update the firefox again

then simply

```
sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
```

Comment: OP wants to skip the downloading update while the terminal is **already** downloading.

Comment: YES DEAR Radu Rădeanu

Comment: please help none of the answerers are doing good

Comment: @user204653 if that is the case please do not accept this one...

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the download process, you will have nothing to update. Anyway, you can do this by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key combination.

If you want to skip some packages for update, you can do this, but *before* to start your update, using the following command:

```
sudo echo "[packagename] hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: OP wants skipping a package from download and not canceling the total update process.CTRL+C he cant use to cancel a specific pakcage update.

Comment: Radu  control c is permanent but  there is a key combo to temp stall commands. From memory: `kill -STOP {id}`  and `kill -CONT {id}` This could be done on a 2nd terminal :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, this is a nice idea, you can add it as answer if you wish.

Comment: I got enough  rep >:D @RaduRădeanu